# Selecting text in parentheses in field using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I have imported CAD annotation and changed it to point feature, and I have the "text string" field in table attribute. Now I want to filter any records that contain the text in parentheses.
For example: the text is "100PVC (2005)" => I want to get "2005"
But the field is more complicated than this example, because some records just like "(05-07)".
I have tried the index function with field calculator but it did not work. I also could not select records which contain the parentheses by using the Select by Attributes. My expression was:

```
[TextString] LIKE '%(____)%'
```

When I verify that it was successfully but no records were returned.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the text between the parenthesis with another % sign eg:

"NAME" LIKE '%(%)%'

This should select all rows with opening and closing parenthesis from my NAME field

Answer (score 2):

For this I would recommend coming to grips with how to use the Field Calculator with the Python parser.  This is described using **[examples in the Online Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002m000000)** but in the case of your specific example I would use something like this:

Parser:

```
Python
```

Expression:

```
Reclass(!TextString!)
```

Code Block:

```
def Reclass(string):
    if string == None:
        return None
    else:
        if "(" in string:
            textInParentheses = string[string.find("(")+1:string.find(")")]
            if "-" in string:
                return "20" + textInParentheses [0:2]
            else:
                return textInParentheses
        else:
            return string
```

Hopefully, this will give you something to work from in order to address all your business rules.  The above just looks for what's between "(" and ")" and if it has a hyphen then just grab the first two characters and put "20" in front of it.